# Blocked loading mixed active content error when loading named map as layer in CARTO?

Tags: javascript, carto, carto-js

I am unable to get my layers to draw on my Carto map using https. My map is created I can see the basemap, but the layers do not draw. The layers load locally, but they won't when I host the site on my server. Instead, I get the error `"Blocked loading mixed active content: “http://[user].carto.com/api/...."`:

I have followed the instructions at [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/213216/applying-https-to-carto-map-but-requesting-insecure-data)  and [CARTO `https-support`](https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js/getting-started/#https-support)

1) I used https when importing both the JS library and the CSS files:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/themes/css/cartodb.css" />
<script src="https://cartodb-libs.global.ssl.fastly.net/cartodb.js/v3/3.15/cartodb.js"></script>
```

2) I am using createLayer, so I set the `{ https: true }` parameter. It looks like this:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
    user_name: '[user]',
    type: 'namedmap',
    https: true,
    named_map: {
        name: "linessimple",
        layers: [{
            layer_name: "t"
        }]
    }
})
.addTo(map);
```

I even tried adding the alert that is suggested in the help documentation. The alert says the layer was loaded, but then the browser blocks it.  Tested in FireFox, Chrome, and Internet Explorer. Same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Checking on old CARTO.js GitHub issues, I have found [a workaround](https://github.com/CartoDB/carto.js/issues/517) that could solve your problem: placing the `https` after the named map definition:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
  user_name: user,
  type: 'namedmap',
  named_map: {
    name: 'name_whatever',
    ...
  }
}, {
  https: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks @ramiroaznar and CARTO support. 
To clarify for anyone else that has this problem. You need to ad the  `{https: true}` argument to **all** CreateLayer functions, even ones that aren't throwing an error in the browser. I had 2 of 3 layers error show errors in the console, even after I added the `{https: true}` argument to those 2 layers. In the end, I also added the argument to the third layer, which wasn't showing an error in the console. Then the errors for the other two went away and everything worked.